# How to display the json message from ajax call

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

How to display the message from ajax call which is type of object

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#checkme').on('click', function () {
    //$('#checkme').attr('disabled',true); 
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '../api/api.php',
      data: $('#tmdt').serialize(),
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function(response) {
        $("#idv").html();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```php
$return_msg = array('response'=>array('status'=>"Transaction type is not valid"));
```

[image]

Comment: try  $("#idv").html(response.status); and try  $("#idv").html(response.response.status);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the format of the returned JSON you can use `response.status`, like this:

```
success: function(data) {
  $("#idv").html(data.response.status);
}
```

Note that if the returned string does not contain HTML, then you can use the `text()` method instead of `html()`.

Answer (score 0):

Update your front end to..

```
success: function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    $("#idv").html(response.response.status);
}
```

Update your backend code to:

```
$return_msg = array('response'=>array('status'=>"Transaction type is not valid"));

echo json_encode($return_msg);
```